# How to extract all reference data from a Wikipedia page?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

Given any page on Wikipedia, such as the one for [Coffee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee), I'm trying to figure out how to extract a list of all references (including any metadata) on the page. At first glance it seems this would be easy, since most pages list them all under a section called References. However, when you examine the wikitext of those pages you find that References is just a pointer to the `ref` template, which I believe generates them dynamically from all of the entries throughout the text on the page.

When I examine the wikitext from sections of text that are connected to each reference, I find that they are enclosed in `<ref></ref>` tags. The content between these tags is dependent on citation type.

So one strategy would be to query all content of the page and do my own parsing to find all `<ref></ref>` pairs. However, I'm thinking there must be a way to do this within the Mediawiki API that I'm not finding. Is there a way? I'd rather pull all of this from wikitext or something other than the final HTML as I expect the former would be more stable.

Comment: I don't know why you've been downvoted - I'd also have thought that there'd be a mediawiki/wikipedia api for getting reference/citation data.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what information exactly you are looking for in the `<ref>`'s, but if you need only the external links, you can really use [MediaWiki API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse) with action *"parse"*:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Coffee&prop=externallinks
```

Answer (score 1):

There are tools that are able to handle the wikipedia xml format:

- Sweble : https://github.com/sweble/sweble-wikitext
- JWPL : https://github.com/dkpro/dkpro-jwpl
- Jsonwikipedia: https://github.com/idio/json-wikipedia

This is a post on some of hte tools for handling wikipedia dumps:
http://engineering.idioplatform.com/2016/02/18/wikipedia-toolkit.html

Another posibiliy (probably even easier) is to use wikidata:

- https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2068675 (it has the references)
- if using wikidata you can probably find the references in the rdf triples or in the huge wikidata json dump
- another possibility is checking wikidata api. i.e: https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q42 (references seem to be there)